# Request timing out when exporting Azure resource group in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to export an ARM template for a resource group in Windows Azure. I'm using the Azure Powershell module.

Whenever I try to export the resource group using `Export-AzResourceGroup`, the cmdlet fails with the following error:

```
Export-AzResourceGroup : Operation failed because a request timed out.
```

I have inspected the web traffic with Fiddler and I can see that the actual HTTP call to Azure is completing successfully, it's just taking a long time. So it's not a matter of e.g. extending the timeout on the `ServicePointManager`.

Is there any solution or work-around to stop this cmdlet timing out?

Answer (score 0):

This issue maybe occurring due to a previous version of Az powershell module. Please update your Az module to the latest version and try again.

Also make sure you have the write permissions in the directory you are trying to create the json file.

Meanwhile, you can create the template from the portal just to check if the json file is getting created successfully:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/export-template-portal#export-template-from-a-resource-group

Comment: I have the latest version of the `Az` module. I also definitely have write permissions. I can create a template for _some_ of my environments this way, but not others, so my setup seems to be sound; it's just that sometimes the cmdlet times out on an opaque condition and I don't see a way to do anything about it.